# color change with input

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

using visual studio, i have 3 errors, all the same with (this.renderer.material.color) in lesson teacher is using mono develop and it's working perfectly for him..

```
public Color changedColor = Color.white;
private Color originalColor = Color.white;

void Awake()
{
    originalColor = this.renderer.material.color;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
    {
        this.renderer.material.color = changedColor;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.G))
    {
        this.renderer.material.color = originalColor;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: render should have written like this(fixed by untity itself) :

this.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;

Comment: and use `Input.GetKey` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error since `MonoBehaviour.renderer` was deprecated a few Unity versions ago, along with other properties such as `collider` or `audio`.

Visual Studio is prompting you to use `GetComponent<T>`, since that's what the component-based game-eninge Unity is all about, you attach and remove components from objects to change their appearance and behaviour.

For example, in your case, you want to modify the `color` of your `renderer`. To change it, first retrieve the instance of `Renderer` from your GameObject.

```
Renderer r = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
```

Then you can access the properties of your renderer, such as `color`.

```
r.color = Color.red;
```